# Dialogflow Fulfillment URLnot sending any data

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am building a bot for google assistant. I have enabled fulfillment section for some intents. Dialog flow sends the request to the fulfillment url. The url is executed and a hard coded response is returned. I can see the response in the assistant simulator. Everything works fine except one thing. The request is empty.I can't access fields that are supposed to be present in the request.

I have accessed the same url using post request from a python code and it displays the parameters. So, there are no issues in the code. I think I am missing some configuration option.

I was expecting the post body in the following format:

```
 POST body:
{
  "responseId": "ea3d77e8-ae27-41a4-9e1d-174bd461b68c",
  "session": "projects/your-agents-project-id/agent/sessions/88d13aa8-2999-4f71-b233-39cbf3a824a0",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "user's original query to your agent",
    "parameters": {
      "param": "param value"
    },
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentText": "Text defined in Dialogflow's console for the intent that was matched",
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            "Text defined in Dialogflow's console for the intent that was matched"
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "outputContexts": [
      {
        "name": "projects/your-agents-project-id/agent/sessions/88d13aa8-2999-4f71-b233-39cbf3a824a0/contexts/generic",
        "lifespanCount": 5,
        "parameters": {
          "param": "param value"
        }
      }
    ],
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/your-agents-project-id/agent/intents/29bcd7f8-f717-4261-a8fd-2d3e451b8af8",
      "displayName": "Matched Intent Name"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
    "diagnosticInfo": {},
    "languageCode": "en"
  },
  "originalDetectIntentRequest": {}
}
```

But when I print the post data using print(request.POST), the actual post request shown is

One more thing: Does dialog flow append the action at the end of the fulfillment url? If so, I will have to handle the logic separately. I have done it without considering the action name. But a lot of my stuff is hacked, so I just want to be sure.

On another note, is dialogflow good enough? It has worked fine on a few examples similar to what it was trained on. How many training samples does it need to work properly? What is the underlying algorithm used in dialogflow? Or should I use the fulfillment url and handle everything on my own? I am inclined towards the later. I do not have too much faith in the existing chatbots.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you update your question to provide details? As it stands right now, it is very difficult to understand and help you diagnose your problem. Including screen shots of the Intents that you expect to be triggered and that are being triggered, the JSON that you're receiving, and details about what parameters you expect and that are missing will help us help you.

Comment: unless you're saying that there was nothing in the post request, your second JSON body didn't make it to the question update.

Answer (score 0):

If the Fallback Intent is the one being triggered, then you wouldn't get any parameters since this means that nothing else matched.

Comment: It is not only for fallback intent. It is for other intents as well.

Comment: The title of your question says "fallback intent", which is part of the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Used request.body. This solves the problem. Then parsed it using json.loads and accessed the parameters.